# process terminated with status -1073740940

Tags: c++

**background:** I was writing a c++ program to solve this problem:

For a positive integer N, the digit-sum of N is defined as the sum of N itself and its digits. When M
is the digitsum of N, we call N a generator of M.For example, the digit-sum of 245 is 256 (= 245 + 2 + 4 + 5). Therefore, 245 is a generator of
256. Not surprisingly, some numbers do not have any generators and some numbers have more than one generator. For example, the generators of 216 are 198 and 207.
You are to write a program to find the smallest generator of the given integer.

Input

Your program is to read from standard input.
The input consists of T test cases.
The number of test cases T is given in the first line of the input.
Each test case takes one line containing an integer N, 1 ≤ N ≤ 100, 000.

Output

Your program is to write to standard output.
Print exactly one line for each test case.
The line is to contain a generator of N for each test case.
If N has multiple generators, print the smallest.
If N does not have any generators, print ‘0’.

**my problem:** the program below always terminated with status -1073740940, I wonder why and need some help

```cpp
int main()
{
    int* ans = new int[100005]();
    int y;
    int i_op;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100001; ++i){
        y = i;
        i_op = i;
        while(i_op){
            y += i_op%10;
            i_op /= 10;
        }
        if(ans[y] == 0 || i < ans[y]){
            ans[y] = i;
        }
    }

    int t;
    int n;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; ++i){
        cin >> n;
        cout << ans[n] << endl;
    }
//========================
//problem occurs here //after doing all output, the process terminated with status -1073740940
//========================

    delete[] ans;

    return 0;
}
```

input data: (both terminated with status -1073740940)

```cpp
10
70587
38943
37061
95352
84205
96532
21150
26337
97804
65891
```

and

```cpp
100000
1
2
……
100000
```

Comment: which compiler, OS ? are you using IDE or command line for running ?

Comment: `-1073740940` = `0xC0000373` = `STATUS_FAILED_STACK_SWITCH` = "_The system was not able to allocate enough memory to perform a stack switch._" Have no idea what that even means.

Comment: Here `ans[y] = i;`, you must check that `y` is not too large for your array.

Comment: Algirdas is off by one, 0xC0000374 tells you that the heap got corrupted.  Which happens when you write past the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be writing past the end of your array during the computation and corrupting something. What happens for i = 99999? I don't think 100005 is quite enough to contain that. Let's check:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int i = 99999;
    int y = i;
    int i_op = i;
    while(i_op){
        y += i_op%10;
        i_op /= 10;
    }
    printf("%d\n", y);
}
```

Outputs 100044. Indeed.